# Formal way to denote "Set of the combinations n of integers that sum to z"

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose I have a set S consisting of the integers [1,5].

How would I formally and generally denote the subset of S that consists of, say, the combinations of 2 integers that sum to 5?  In this example the answer would be

{{1,4},{2,3}}

I believe a formal and general representation of this subset would involve the combination operator (ie $\binom{r}{k}$), but I'm not quite sure if that is the right approach.  I'm working on a proof and need to be able to clearly articulate this idea in a general manner.

Comment: $$\{X\subseteq S:\sum_{x\in X}x=5\}$$or more succinctly $$\{X\subseteq S:\sum X=5\}$$but in that case you probably should define $\sum X$ (the sum of all the elements of $X$) as I'm not sure that is standard notation.

Comment: I initially did this too, but its not right.  I need the subset of n integers that sum to z.  This gives the subsets of any number of integers that sum to a value.

Comment: Just add the additional criteria, *vis*: $~\{X\subseteq S: \lvert X\rvert =n, \sum X = z\}$

Comment: lmao duh.  haha ths.  @bof if you correct your submission ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all $n$-element subsets of $S$ that sum to $z$ could be denoted by
$$\{X\subseteq S:|X|=n\text{ and }\sum X=z\}$$
or
$$\{X\in\binom Sn:\sum X=z\}$$
or
$$\{X\in[S]^n:\sum X=z\}.$$
Both $\binom Sn$ and $[S]^n$ have been used to denote the set of all $n$-element subsets of a set $S.$